# Mistake in calculating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x(1+x^2)}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Mistake in calculating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x(1+x^2)}$

I want to use Residue theorem. Consider the function $$f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{z(1+z^2)}$$
We integrate it over a semicircle $C_R$ with a small semicircle $C_{\epsilon}$ around $0$ to avoid the pole at $0$. I showed that the integral over $C_R$ goes to $0$ using Jordan's lemma. Now around $C_\epsilon$ we can use indentation lemma. The Residue at $0$ is $1$ thus the integral over $C_\epsilon$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ is $\pi$ (I think here is my mistake but I don't see how this is wrong). Thus we have $$\pi +\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{iz}}{z(1+z^2)}=2\pi i(Residue)$$ The residue at $z=i$ is $-\frac{1}{2e}$ thus taking imaginary parts of both sides I get that the integral is $-\pi/e$ which is incorrect. I suspect that the integral over $C_{\epsilon}$ goes to $\pi *i$ but i cannot see why that would be the case.

Comment: The integral about a small arc of angle $\theta$ about $a\in\mathbb{C}$ as $\epsilon\to0$ is given by$$i\cdot\theta\cdot\text{res}(f,a)$$

Comment: @PeterForeman ugh, you are right! Thank you :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's parameterize $C_{\epsilon}$ as $z(t) = \epsilon e^{i\pi  - it}= -\epsilon e^{-it}$ for $0\leq t \leq \pi$. Note that $z(0) = -\epsilon$, $z(\pi) = \epsilon$, and $z(t)$ traverses the upper semicircle from left to right.

Since this means $dz = i\epsilon e^{-it}\; dt$, we then have

$$\int_{C_{\epsilon}}\frac{e^{iz}}{z(1+z^2)}\; dz
= \int_0^{\pi}\; \frac{e^{-i\epsilon e^{-it}}}{-\epsilon e^{-it}(1+\epsilon^2 e^{-2it})} (i\epsilon e^{-it})\; dt$$
$$= -i\int_0^{\pi}\; \frac{e^{-i\epsilon e^{-it}}}{1+\epsilon^2 e^{-2it}} \; dt$$

The integrand converges to $1$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, so the integral converges to
$$-it\Bigg|_{t=0}^{\pi} = -i\pi$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x} \over x\pars{1 + x^{2}}}\,\dd x & =
\Im\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic x} - 1\over
x\pars{x + \ic}\pars{x - \ic}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\Im\bracks{2\pi\ic\,
{\expo{\ic\pars{\ic}} - 1 \over \pars{\ic}\pars{\ic + \ic}}} =
2\pi\,{{\expo{-1} - 1 \over -2}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\large{\pi\pars{\expo{} - 1} \over \expo{}}}
\approx 1.9859 \\ &
\end{align}
The integral path is *"closed"* with a semicircle in the upper complex plane.

Comment: That is a cool way of getting rid of the pole, as it does not influence the imaginary part! Thank you.

Comment: @2132123 The main purpose is to avoid the integral divergence at $\displaystyle x = 0$. Thanks.